# Can't access airflow UI

Tags: python, webserver, airflow, rhel

I am trying to install Apache airflow 2.1.0 on red hat guest virtual machine. I am a newbie with airflow as I want to learn how to use it to create ETL.
I am pretty stuck with airflow webserver.

airflow db init works alright.

```
Initialization done.
```

I created an admin user after db initialization.
Then problem arrives with airflow webserver command.

```
[priya@localhost ~]$ airflow webserver -D
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
[2021-06-29 00:10:30,556] {dagbag.py:487} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /dev/null
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
Access Logformat: 
=================================================================
```

After this I thought to access UI by http://localhost:8080 and url is not locating.

I again tried

```
[priya@localhost ~]$ airflow webserver -D
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
[2021-06-29 00:19:30,546] {dagbag.py:487} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /dev/null
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/webserver_command.py", line 368, in webserver
    check_if_pidfile_process_is_running(pid_file=pid_file, process_name="webserver")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 267, in check_if_pidfile_process_is_running
    raise AirflowException(f"The {process_name} is already running under PID {pid}.")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The webserver is already running under PID 3147.
```

webserver seems to run on pid 3147 then why can't I access webserver UI?

Also, I tried to do `airflow webserver -p 8080` but then it keeps on giving me error logs
workers initialize...workers timeout... in infinite loop.

Kindly help. Thank you!

Comment: Try to kill the process with `kill -9 3147` then delete the `airflow-webserver.pid` file and try running airflow `webserver -p 8080` again.

Comment: Hi I killed the process 3147 but I do not know how to delete the .pid file. Can you please help? Thank you.

Comment: It's repeating the same error. https://imgur.com/a/KTvrVxS
Only when I do ```webserver -D``` it says ```webserver running``` . on doing ```airflow webserver -p 8080``` it does this loop.

Answer (score 1):

It should work with the first command. It has nothing to do with Airflow, it's the way how networking works with guest virtual machines.

The problem is that if you run it in guest virtual machine, the machine (and Airflow) is available not on localhost (which is your host machine) but at the IP address of the virtual machine.

This will be usually address with '192.168.0.' or '172.x.y.z' or similar.
You can get all addresses of your guest machine via `ip addr` command for example.

So your Airflow URL will be something like `http://192.168.0.n:8080` not `0.0.0.0:8080`.

In some cases (depending how you manage your virtual machine) you can configure port forwarding so that your local port 8080 is forwarded to the guest IP address automatically, but it depends on your vm software.

Comment: I started webserver again with ```airflow webserver -D``` and did ```http://10.0.2.15:8080```.... I can't access the UI . the IP address of my VM machine is 10.0.2.15/24

Comment: What you can do is inside the virtual machine try if you can access the website. A simple `wget localhost:8080` should be enough to tell you whether it can reach it. Now if that works, you want to find your local ip, which you already did. Then try again, if it is not finding it, that means you need to port forward it inside the guest machine. Searching for your virtualization software with "port forwarding" on google should help make it easy for you to enable port forwarding for TCP 8080.

Comment: I think I am having a similar issue - do I need to change the airflow.cfg file to prefix with guest machine address before 8080?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68173833/cant-access-airflow-ui

Answer (score 0):

You might need a port forward:

```
sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp
```

Check it out:

```
sudo ufw status
```

It should contain the following line:

`8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)`

Now try to visit the address: http://<your_ip>:8080

Answer (score 0):

Like aforementioned comments, It has nothing to do with Airflow. It is due to the problem in the network of your virtual machine.
If you use Docker, you can follow this to solve the problem.
In Docker, whenever you do something in a specific container. This container is isolated, which means that the network within a container is different from that of your host machine.
So the key to this question is that you have to map the ports between the host machine and the virtual machine (docker container) via -P or -p when you run the Docker Images to create a docker container.